# Nullpointer exception in Hashmaps

Tags: java

I’m trying to add Products to my `OrderLine` (which is held by an Order) but when I try I get the `NullPointerException`.

```
import java.util.*;
public class OrderLine;

private HashMap<Integer, Integer> products = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

//setter and getter for products

public void add(int productNbr, int amount) {
    int newAmount = this.products.get(productNbr) + amount;
    this.products.put(productNbr, newAmount);
}
```

And my Main-tester;

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

OrderLine ol = new OrderLine();
ol.add(1, 661);
ol.add(1, 5); //key 1 should hold value 666
System.out.println(ol.getProducts()); //Should print out {1, 666}
```

But all I get is "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException". 
I get the feeling that it works if I define/initiate the value before I add anything to it, but I shouldn't have to do that every time. Any ideas?

**UPDATE: Fixed version;**

```
public void add(int productNbr, int amount) {
    if (this.products.get(productNbr) != null) {
        int newAmount = this.products.get(productNbr) + amount;
        this.products.put(productNbr, newAmount);
    } else {
        this.products.put(productNbr, amount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about what `this.products.get(productNbr)` returns if you have an empty HashMap. Is there some way you could use an if statement to decide whether or not you're adding the first instance of that product?

Comment: a duplicated just for having "Nullpointer exception" on the title!!!!!

Comment: You want to use `Map.compute` i.e. `products.compute(productNbr, (k, v) -> (v == null) ? amount : v + amount);` This will handle the case where there was no previous value.